# Search multiple files in a word and replace it to single word on a click event

Tags: c#

I need to search the words in a log file like `"INFO"`, `"ERROR"`, `"FATAL"` in a file and need to replace it to the word `"DEBUG"` on the check box click. If I uncheck the box, the words from `"DEBUG"` should replaced to the original state like `"INFO"`, `"ERROR"` e.t.c.

I tried to use `File.Replace()` method. But it is helpful for searching & replacing only one word. I am not sure how to handle it Array or something. Also, how to hold the previous state of the file.

I used the below code. But somewhere I am doing a mistake.

```
private void ToggleforDebugMode(bool IsDebug)
{
    string text = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hi.config";
    string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName("Hi.config") + fileName;
    text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hi.config");
    if (IsDebug)
    {
        _previousState = text.Contains("WARN") ? "WARN" : "INFO";

        if(text.Contains("WARN"))
        {
            text = text.Replace("WARN", "DEBUG");
        }
        else if (text.Contains("DEBUG"))
        {
            text = text.Replace("INFO", "DEBUG");
        }               

    }
    else
    {
         text = text.Replace("DEBUG", _previousState);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Galileo Print Manager .NET\GPM_Service.exe.config", text);
}
```

Comment: Just create string array and use `for`, `foreach` or other iteration methods.

Comment: why people marking downvote, What is the problem with this question?

Comment: Agree, don’t understand why this is being down voted.

Comment: Priya, please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why this question receives negative votes, it is an interesting question because it proposes a concept that can be useful for future readers with the same problem or a similar one.

@Priya, I have created this method that replaces all the words that you specify with a specific word

In this example, `"FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN"` with `"FUNNY"` are replaced

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Test.txt";
PriyaMethod(path, true, "FUNNY", "FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN");
```

Also, as you can see, I use a `string` to save the previous state of the contents of the file to call when it needs to be restored.

---

```
        using System.IO;

        //Save the original content to restore it when required
        private string SavedState = String.Empty;

        private void PriyaMethod(string FilePath, bool IsDebug, string ReplaceWord, params string[] WordsToReplace)
        {
            //string[] WordsToUse = { "INFO", "ERROR", "FATAL", "DEBUG", "WARN" };

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                // string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
                // string[] Words = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath).Split(' 
                 string Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
                // byte[] Bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                // IEnumerable<string> ReadLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(FilePath);*/

                 SavedState = Text;

                 if (IsDebug)
                 {

                    for (int i = 0; i < WordsToReplace.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        Text = Text.Replace(WordsToReplace[i], ReplaceWord);
                    }

                    //If the file is open, it closes it to prevent an IOException from occurring
                    File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read).Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(FilePath, Text); //Write new content
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    //If the file is open, it closes it to prevent an IOException from occurring
                    File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read).Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(FilePath, SavedState); //Restore old content
                 }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(System.String.Format("The file {0} does not exists", FilePath));
            }
        }
```

---

If you want skip line:

```
string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);

int LinePosition = 0; // First line

Lines[LinePosition] = String.Empty // Delete selected line
```

Or

```
string Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

string[] Lines = Content.Split('\n');

int LinePosition = 1; // Second line

Lines[LinePosition] = null // Delete selected line
```

Assembly NewContent:

```
string NewContent = String.Empty; // Content without selected line

// Assembly new content
foreach(string Line in Lines) NewContent += Line + "\n";

//Or

// Assembly new content
foreach(string Line in Lines) NewContent += String.Format("{0}{1}", Line, "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks Hector, This piece of code works. But I could not restore to the initial values as the values in the object "path" gets refreshed even though we save the data by reading the file without executing the method.

Comment: @Priya 
Why do not you try to save them using `User Settings`? [Here is a tutorial](https://youtu.be/7to8KHsXspE)

Comment: Thanks Hector. Is there any way I can skip a particular line while reading the contents of the file.

Comment: @Priya Sure, look at my post, I added this

Comment: @Priya 
I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so writing an answer. Your else statement is wrong:

```
else if (text.Contains("DEBUG"))
```

Should be:

```
else if (text.Contains("INFO"))
```

I assumed your text does not contain both `"WARN"` and `"INFO"`. If it does, the `previousState` thing will not work.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Anyway, how to search for a multiple words in a file. In else if part, I  am checking only for only one word.

Comment: If the text is not huge I would just keep 2 copies of it in memory. Like `var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hi.config");
var replacedText = text.Replace("WARN", "DEBUG").Replace("INFO", "DEBUG");`

and return text or replacedText based on IsDebug flag. There are definitely more optimal solutions but this is pretty simple